# Neural network doesn't accept grayscale images

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I followed this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/11/object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/
I changed this part where I converted the image feed to grayscale before inserting it to the neural network

```
frame = vs.read()
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

(h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)),
    0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
```

However this error occurs:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (ngroups > 0 && inpCn % ngroups == 0 && outCn % ngroups == 0) in cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\dnn\src\layers\convolution_layer.cpp, line 234
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Toshiba/PycharmProjects/real-time-object-detection/study7ver2.py", line 75, in <module>
        detections = net.forward()
    cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\dnn\src\layers\convolution_layer.cpp:234: error: (-215) ngroups > 0 && inpCn % ngroups == 0 && outCn % ngroups == 0 in function cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes
```

Line 75 is: `detections = net.forward()`

Why do I want to convert it to grayscale? Because I need to do histogram equalization before feeding the image to neural network so that the image feed at night time will be clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vast majority of these models require color, i.e. *3-channel* images; by converting to grayscale you end up with a single-channel image, and the code crashes.

Let's have a quick look to confirm this; the script in the linked blog post is run as

```
python deep_learning_object_detection.py \
    --prototxt MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt \
    --model MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel --image images/example_01.jpg
```

Digging into the [`MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt`](https://github.com/chuanqi305/MobileNet-SSD/blob/master/MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt) file of the [MobileNet-SSD Github repo](https://github.com/chuanqi305/MobileNet-SSD) (i.e. the implementation used here), we see that the input layer is defined as

```
name: "MobileNet-SSD"
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
  dim: 300
  dim: 300
}
```

The second `dim` argument here is exactly the number of channels expected in the image (3). And it will simply refuse to work for single-channel images, such as grayscale ones.

A *hack* in similar cases, just to keep you playing along (although I have seen it routinely used in medical & satellite imaging, where also the images are often not color ones), is just to *replicate* your single-channel into 3 identical ones, and combine them to form a "3-channel" image...

Comment: Thanks for the hack but could you give me a link of a tutorial or discussion about that hack. I'm not a python/opencv expert so I'm having a difficult time searching using the right terminologies.

Comment: @MaeBaes See [Splitting and Merging Image Channels](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#splitting-and-merging-image-channels) in the OpenCV Python documentation.